# Resharper. How to add xaml template

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

How to add in the Resharper template with .xaml extension? 
 For example, I am trying to add a Window.xaml and the problem is in this line 
              `<Window x:Class="ADONET_Samples.UserControls.Window1"` how to put in "Window1" the name of your XAML form.

```
<Window x:Class="ADONET_Samples.UserControls.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ADONET_Samples.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more in detail? Do you want to simply enter a string? You could do this with a variable like this: `<Window x:Class="$Class$"`

Comment: I like to use hotkeys, In ReSharper - ctrl+Insert let me various templates to automatically create Class, Interface, etc, but doesn't have any various to create Windows1.xaml forms. Your answer - <Window x:Class="$Class$" doesn't work. It just put Class, without project name+form name. When I use a classic method to add Windows1.xaml form, Visual studio gives it a full name like this <Window x:Class="ADONET_Samples.UserControls.Window1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you have to use a multifile template. Do it like this:

1. Copy the code at the end of this post into a text file called `WindowTemplate.DotSettings`.
2. Open the ReSharper Templates Explorer via *Extensions → ReSharper → Tools → Templates Explorer...*.
3. Open the tab *File Templates* and import the file `WindowTemplate.DotSettings`.

You should see a template called *Custom Window*. If you're interested in the code, you can open it.You can also add the template to the quicklist when setting the layer within Templates Explorer to *Smart*.

When using `Alt` + `Insert` in Solution Explorer and opening *More...*, there will be the template. Choose it an enter a name for the file. Now the code generation is done.

However, you won't be able to compile it with the following error: `CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context`. You have to solve this manually for every file by opening the `*.csproj` file and looking for the following code:

```
<AdditionalFiles Include="Demo3.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</AdditionalFiles>
```

Replace it with (notice `Page` instead of `AdditionalFile`):

```
<Page Include="Demo3.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
```

Last but not least, the necessary template code:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Description/@EntryValue">Custom Window</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Text/@EntryValue">&lt;Window x:Class="$Namespace$.$Class$"&#xD;
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"&#xD;
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"&#xD;
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"&#xD;
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"&#xD;
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:$Namespace$"&#xD;
    mc:Ignorable="d"&#xD;
    Title="$Class$" Height="450" Width="800"&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Grid&gt;&#xD;
&#xD;
&lt;/Grid&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/Window&gt;</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Reformat/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/ShortenQualifiedReferences/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/CustomProperties/=FileName/@EntryIndexedValue">Window</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/CustomProperties/=Extension/@EntryIndexedValue">xaml</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/CustomProperties/=ValidateFileName/@EntryIndexedValue">False</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Applicability/=File/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Scope/=55C906A5BD591341AE313A07A8F303DE/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Scope/=55C906A5BD591341AE313A07A8F303DE/Type/@EntryValue">InAnyXamlProject</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Field/=Namespace/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Field/=Namespace/Expression/@EntryValue">fileDefaultNamespace()</s:String>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Field/=Namespace/InitialRange/@EntryValue">-1</s:Int64>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Field/=Namespace/Order/@EntryValue">0</s:Int64>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Field/=Class/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Field/=Class/Expression/@EntryValue">getAlphaNumericMainFileNameWithoutExtension()</s:String>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Field/=Class/InitialRange/@EntryValue">-1</s:Int64>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Field/=Class/Order/@EntryValue">1</s:Int64>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Section/=60769A869101874889D7DC3F51C8EEA7/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Section/=60769A869101874889D7DC3F51C8EEA7/LocationSelectorName/@EntryValue">manual</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Section/=60769A869101874889D7DC3F51C8EEA7/LocationSelectorConfig/@EntryValue">&lt;RelativeConfig File="$NAME$.xaml.cs" /&gt;</s:String>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Section/=60769A869101874889D7DC3F51C8EEA7/Order/@EntryValue">0</s:Int64>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=0CB2F5C22C4A274F8D1425E1F1DA05CF/Section/=60769A869101874889D7DC3F51C8EEA7/SectionPlain/Text/@EntryValue">using System;&#xD;
using System.Collections.Generic;&#xD;
using System.Linq;&#xD;
using System.Text;&#xD;
using System.Threading.Tasks;&#xD;
using System.Windows;&#xD;
using System.Windows.Controls;&#xD;
using System.Windows.Data;&#xD;
using System.Windows.Documents;&#xD;
using System.Windows.Input;&#xD;
using System.Windows.Media;&#xD;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;&#xD;
using System.Windows.Navigation;&#xD;
using System.Windows.Shapes;&#xD;
&#xD;
namespace $Namespace$&#xD;
{&#xD;
    /// &lt;summary&gt;&#xD;
    /// Interaction logic for $Class$.xaml&#xD;
    /// &lt;/summary&gt;&#xD;
    public partial class $Class$ : Window&#xD;
    {&#xD;
        public $Class$()&#xD;
        {&#xD;
            InitializeComponent();&#xD;
        }&#xD;
    }&#xD;
}&#xD;
</s:String></wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks, Just for the $Class$ set macros "Current file name without extension"